# Get current credentials on the server side silverlight ria services

Tags: web-services, silverlight, authentication, ria

I have Silverlight web app. And it includes web client side (one assembly) and server side of ria services (other assembly).
Windows Authentication to webapp is provided by standart `public class AuthenticationDomainService : AuthenticationBase<User>` and it works fine. But on the server side i can get only user Name (login)

I need send WebRequest from the server side to asmx-service. I try to pass credentials of current user next way:

```
webRequest.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
```

or

```
webRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("AD login", "AD password");
```

But in one case it doesn't work and in second i need to get also password.

ASMX-service is hosted on IIS with Windows authentication.

How can i pass current credentials from server side of ria services to WebRequest?